# Main breaker outside as disconnect. Do i need a main breaker inside too?

Tags: electrical

I have a 125 amp main disconnect outside. I have an old fp panel inside back to back. Can i get a lug panel inside or do i need a main breaker inside too to comply w 2014 nec?

Comment: Is the existing main disconnect your service equipment? (i.e. is the connection between neutral and ground made in the main disconnect?)

Comment: I will look in th am. Im not home now. But if it is bonded oitside then i should be good inside. If they are straight thru then id need a main inside too?

Comment: Could i just bond them if its not?

Comment: Is the existing panel main lug, main breaker, or rule-of-six/split-bus btw? Also, the 125A breaker outside is *not* labeled as a meter disconnect, right?

Comment: Yes. It says main disconnect. The outside main is back to back w the inside and within 6 feet of panel. 2 feet from exterior door.

Comment: Is the conduit connecting the two boxes metal or plastic btw?

Comment: Emt from meter to main.

Comment: From out to in i imagine would be literally back to back. Chase nipple maybe.

Comment: That's good news though, it means you can use a main panel of any size, you aren't chained to a panel size which corresponds to your service.  So you can have a larger panel and more expansion room.